# windows boot loader does not detect ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I installed ubuntu 13.04 along side windows 7. However, after installation was complete and the computer restarted I could not see ubuntu in the operating system load choice. I had windows 7 initially and 3 drives c,d and e before I installed ubuntu. I deleted e: partition and installed ubuntu in the unallocated space.

Windows boot loaded does not detect ubuntu 13.04.

please help

Comment: You should have installed Windows first, then Ubuntu second.. that way the system will use the Ubuntu Bootloader and grub to startup

Answer (score 1):

Windows bootloader is not going to see Ubuntu by itself. You need an [application called EasyBCD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD) or edit config manually.